# Confusion regarding helicopter?

Tags: helicopter

Is there any difference for the case when helicopter rotor spins clockwise and the case when helicopter rotor spins anticlockwise? Is it something like clockwise spinning will cause the helicopter to move up and to move down for anti clock wise?

Comment: Helicopter blades always produce downward thrust. The amount of thrust will determine whether the helicopter is moving up, or down, or hovering stationary. The amount of thrust is controlled by blade pitch, not direction of rotation.

Comment: [This](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39382/it-is-possible-to-feel-a-difference-between-helicopters-with-clockwise-direction) might also be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Helicopter rotors are designed to rotate only in one direction. But the designer can freely choose the direction, and both clockwise and counter-clockwise rotors are commonly found in service today.

The rotor torque and some aerodynamic effects are based on the direction of rotation, and so these effects can be in opposite directions between a clockwise and a counter-clockwise rotating helicopter. But "up to symmetry" the effects are identical.

Thrust is adjusted by varying the pitch of the rotor blades, not by changing the speed or the direction of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Rotors only spin one way at all times, like airplane propellers, because thrust is adjusted with blade pitch (even with a propeller that has reverse thrust, it's done by reversing the pitch, not by driving the prop in the other direction).

But you'll find rotors spin in different directions depend on manufacturer. Generally in NA helicopters are counterclockwise looking down. Some European machines spin the opposite way.

The biggest practical effect is the direction of rotation determines the left/right orientation of certain tail rotor control characteristics, because the tail rotor is making its thrust blowing air left or right depending on the main rotor's torque direction.

More importantly, it determines the direction to roll if you are ditching the thing in water, to make sure the blades contact the water behind you. If you have to set a land based Bell 206 on the water (assuming no airbag safety system so you are going on your side anyway), you initiate a roll to the ***right*** at touchdown ***toward*** the advancing blade, so that the first blade that hits the water hard enough to stop it does so to the right of the machine and the following blades slam into the water more or less over the tail boom. Roll the other way so the blades contact the water left side first, the blades following the first one to stop can come into the cockpit roof.

If your machine's rotor spins clockwise from above, like most Eurocopter machines, you roll it to the ***left*** to get the same effect.